# debugging ajp on tomcat

Tags: debugging, tomcat6, apache, ajp

tomcat 6.0.30 crashes whenever apache http server forward the web request to it via ajp.  It by itself is fine to handle the same request via http 8080.  how do I debug this problem?  what could be the problem?

Comment: the problem was due to system time set to an old date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for http 8080 is  ok, so I guess ajp connector is blocking or slower response.You can use tcpdump to monitor traffic between apache and tomcat. or kill -3 to see stack info.